# Two Foreign Keys Refer same column of another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-key-relationship

I have two relations like this,
user(user_id, user_name)
messages(sender,reciever,time,message)
in here both sender and reciever refers user_id of the user table.
I need to write a query to get sender's user_name recievers user_name , message.

Comment: Did you run into some difficulties?

Comment: You either need to write a join query or use two nested queries to get that information. If you write some code and have trouble, edit the post so that you can get help. You're not going to find someone to write it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JOIN` with the referring table twice like

```
select u1.user_name as Sender,
u2.user_name as Receiver,
m.message
from messages m
join user u1 on m.sender = u1.user_id
join user u2 on m.receiver = u2.user_id;
```